# rsync curly braces with one item issue?

Tags: rsync, braces

I have a problem with rsync when I pass the exclude list in curly braces, what is the difference between the following two lines?

```
sudo rsync -aHAXxhvi --delete --exclude={/1111111/} /etc/ /media/destino/etc/

sudo rsync -aHAXxhvi --delete --exclude={/1111111/,} /etc/ /media/destino/etc/
```

With the first one, the directory /etc/111111 is copied, the exclude does not work and with the second one it is not copied, the only difference is the comma.

Is this the expected behavior?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are expanded by your shell (bash/zsh), not by rsync. (For example, if you have a two-item list, the shell expands it to two separate "--exclude=" options.)

Yes, in shell syntax, [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) only happens if there are at least two elements:

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and **at least one unquoted comma** or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has solved my question.
I couldn't find any information, because I thought the expansion was done by rsync instead of the bash shell.

Greetings.